# Como poner un una variable que incremente automaticamente cada vez que se cree un objeto de dicha variable

Tags: java

Tengo una clase Cita con una id, la idea es que automáticamente se cree una id nueva cada vez que yo cree un objeto de esa clase. Es decir, cada vez que yo cree una cita tenga un id distinto.

```
public class Cita {

    private int numerocita;
    private Paciente pac;
    private Date hora;

    public Cita(int numerocita, Paciente pac, Date hora) {
        this.numerocita = numerocita;
        this.pac = pac;
        this.hora = hora;
    }

    public Cita() {

    }

    public int getNumerocita() {
        return numerocita;
    }

    public void setNumerocita(int numerocita) {
        this.numerocita = numerocita;
    }

    public Paciente getPac() {
        return pac;
    }

    public void setPac(Paciente pac) {
        this.pac = pac;
    }

    public Date getHora() {
        return hora;
    }

    public void setHora(Date hora) {
        this.hora = hora;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Creo que lo que estas buscando es algo como esto

```
public class Cita {

    private static int contador = 0;
    ...

    public Cita(int numerocita, Paciente pac, Date hora) {
        this.numerocita = numerocita;
        this.pac = pac;
        this.hora = hora;
        incrementarContador();
    }

    public Cita() {
        incrementarContador();
    }

    private static void incrementarContador() {
        contador++;
    }

    public static int obtenerContador() {
        return contador;
    }
}
```

Al hacer una variable static lo que logras es que todas las instancias de la clase compartan el mismo valor.

Comment: Es que yo no quiero eso, yo quiero que cada lista de citas tenga uan id, cada vez que tu crees uan cita tiene que tener una id, para cada doctor osea

el doctor manolo tiene una lista de citas con ID 1 2 3 4 5 segun el nº de citas
el doctor Perico tiene otra lista de citas con id 1 2 3 
el otro pues igual
todas empiezan en 1 2 3 4 pero se incrementan segun le voy añadiendo

Comment: @unknow, veo que en cada respuesta que te han dado, ambas correctas, haces referencia a dos listas de `Cita`s, pero en tu pregunta no hay nada de esto. Te recomeindo que expliques correctamente el comportamiento que deseas tener y que agregues el código que tienes para implementarlo. Por otras parte, lo que comentas no lo puedes lograr desde la clase `Cita`, este control sobre los identificadores lo vas a tener que implementar en otra clase.

Comment: y como hago eso?

Answer (score 4):

Si bien te han dado una respuesta que puede ser de utilidad, la misma tiene un detalle de unicidad.

Tienes un programa que genera citas. Necesitas que las mismas tengan un `id` diferente para cada cita que generas al crear una instancia de la clase Cita.

Uno de los problemas que se presentan al usar un valor de auto incremento directamente en la Clase, tal como propone la otra respuesta, es que cuando tu programa se cierra y se vuelve a abrir, el valor del contador nuevamente está en cero, sin importar cuantas citas hayas generado en la sesión anterior del programa.

Esto sucede porque dicho contador permanece en memoria, siempre y cuando el programa también se encuentre en ejecución (en memoria).

#### Solución

Yo usaría un generador de valores aleatorios que me garanticen unicidad en el sistema en el que se ejecuta el programa, independientemente de si el programa se cierra y se vuelve a abrir.

Ahora, en tu código no hay ningún atributo que indique o haga referencia a un `id`, y lo único que tienes es una propiedad de la clase Cita que se llama `numerocita`, sin embargo no das detalles de cómo obtienes o creas dicho valor.

Si vas a usar dicho valor como `id` de Cita, debes garantizar que el mismo sea único, tanto al crear una instancia de la clase usando el constructor: `Cita()`, como al pasarle el número de la cita usando el constructor con parámetros: `Cita(<nrocita>,<paciente>,<fecha>)`.

Como no indicas si ese será el atributo que quieres como `id`, voy a crear un atributo en la clase Cita y trabajaré sobre el mismo, sin alterar tu clase actual. (Tal como hicieron en la otra respuesta).

Para generar valores aleatorios usaré la Clase [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) de Java, y en particular el método [`randomUUID()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID()).

Como dicho método devuelve un objeto UUID, usaré el método [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#toString()) de dicho objeto para obtener una representación en `String` del objeto.

Por lo tanto nuestro atributo `id` de la clase Cita lo vamos a declarar como tipo `String`.

Una forma en la que puede quedar tu código sería la siguiente (he implementado una clase básica basada en tu clase Cita, no necesariamente es la misma clase, pero sirve de ejemplo).

```java
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.Date;

class Cita {
  private int numerocita;
  private String id;
  private String pac;
  private Date hora;

  public Cita(int numerocita, String pac, Date hora) {
      this.numerocita = numerocita;
      this.pac = pac;
      this.hora = hora;
      // generamos un id único
      this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  }

  public Cita() {
    // generamos un id único
    this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  }

  public int getNumerocita() {
      return numerocita;
  }

  public void setNumerocita(int numerocita) {
      this.numerocita = numerocita;
  }

  public String getPac() {
      return pac;
  }

  public void setPac(String pac) {
      this.pac = pac;
  }

  public Date getHora() {
      return hora;
  }

  public void setHora(Date hora) {
      this.hora = hora;
  }

  public String getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

}

public class generarCitas {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // creamos 3 citas y verificamos que tengan id diferente:
    Date fecha1 = new Date();
    Cita cita1 = new Cita(1001, "Mauricio Contreras", fecha1);

    Date fecha2 = new Date();
    Cita cita2 = new Cita(1002, "Andrés Contreras", fecha2);

    Date fecha3 = new Date();
    Cita cita3 = new Cita(1003, "Ernesto Contreras", fecha3);

    System.out.println(cita1.getId());
    System.out.println(cita2.getId());
    System.out.println(cita3.getId());

  }
}
```

Si corremos varias veces este programa, los valores de `id` siempre serán diferentes:

[image: Ejemplo de salida del programa]

De esta forma cada cita que generes tendrá un valor `id` único y diferente de otra cita ya generada.

Obviamente este valor no es de auto incremento, pero para que un valor de auto incremento sea único con cada ejecución del programa, debes tener una forma de persistir el último valor generado, y eso es harina de otro costal.

Si usamos el enfoque de la otra respuesta, el resultado sería el siguiente:

[image: Resultado usando el otro enfoque]

Dando como resultado lo que comenté al principio.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Necesito una id de citas que sea  1 2 3 4 tiene que ser asi, y cada lista de citas tiene que tener su propio orden de ID osea la id de la lista de citas del doctor manolo no tiene nada que ver con las ids de citas del doctor pedro